# Usage of "Apologize" without "I"

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Is it intrinsically means that these both are almost equal ?

Does "Kindly apologize.."  always means "**I** kindly apologize.."

or

"Kindly apologize for the issue" can **also** mean "You kindly need to apologize for the issue"

Please throw some light on the usage and how it can be interpreted ?

This was put on an email thread at the bottom of the mail. 
I had checked few references but none of them gave a clear picture of the situation.

Answer (score 2):

It's *always* the second one. Without a subject, using the verb like this is using the [***imperative mood***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood), that is to say, you're giving an order or command.

So:

> "I turn the steering wheel"

It's me, turning the steering wheel.

> "Turn the steering wheel"

You, the person I am talking to, I am telling you that you should turn the steering wheel.

It uses the infinitive form of the verb: "to apologize" becomes "apologize", "to be" becomes "be".

Note also that if I say:

> Ball, be red.

Ball is *not* the subject here, and this is still an imperative statement and an instruction -- I am telling the ball that it should be red.

Given your question, you may also want to know that if *you* want to apologize, a common form is "please accept my apologies". Saying "I kindly apologize" is not something a native speaker would say, and sounds quite rude.

Comment: I would agree with this answer, for my version of English. But given that the OP appears to assume that the default meaning is "I apologise", I wonder if that might be true in Indian English? Do Indian correspondents perhaps write "Kindly apologize" to mean "I kindly apologize"?

Comment: @ColinFine Possible, I guess, and something I'd not thought of.

Comment: I agree: (1) ***I*** would interpret “Kindly apologize” as a request, and not an apology, unless the context weighed *heavily* in favor of the latter, but (2) I can easily imagine an ESL person using it the other way. (A few years ago I had some dealings with some Japanese people who were functional in English but not really fluent.  I don’t recall hearing this particular usage, but it sounds a little like the sort of thing they would say.)